# Keyboard dismiss taking space in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard

Whenever i dismiss the keyboard sometimes it is taking space at half of the screen whether in iOS or Android. Below is the screenshot why i'm facing this issue. This picture is when after i dismiss the keyboard.

[image: Pic]

> TestPage.dart

```
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestPage> createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          SizedBox(height: 50.0,),
          TextField(),
          SizedBox(height: 50.0,),
          TextField()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Attach your code, it will be helpful to check your problem

Comment: May be you have added bottom padding or your column is not talking full width

Comment: @HarishSharma Added sample code

Answer (score 0):

Hey did you try to set `background color` to your scaffold like below

```
class TestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestPage> createState() => _TestPageState();
}

class _TestPageState extends State<TestPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      body: ListView(
        children: const [
          SizedBox(height: 50.0,),
          TextField(),
          SizedBox(height: 50.0,),
          TextField()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's just a sample code

Comment: Yes i understand but i can't give proper solution until you share your original UI code here because there is some issue in your UI code either it's have some padding or margin from bottom or your ui is not taking whole height